# PHP: Loading up an HTML file without it tidying my code

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I am using the loadhtml function ([http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.phpt](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)) to load up an external .html file.  When I load it, it "tidy's" up my code, which, I don't want.  I do NOT want a full HTML document, I only want html snippets in my .html, and I don't want the loadhtml file to try to make it valid html, because I don't want it to.

Is there a better function to load up a .html file so that it does not tidy up the code?!

Comment: What do you want to do with the loaded up html file?  That'll effect the answers you get.

Comment: I want to load it up into a <textarea> tag so that I can edit it then post it back to the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to just put the HTML into a string, you can just use:

```
$file1 = file_get_contents("file.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

LoadHTML puts your html file data into a DOM structure.

If it is not really HTML (snippets aren't) then you can't really make a DOM structure -- but that is what you asked for.

Now, the first question comment asked what you wanted to do once this data was loaded, so either you have a good answer for that which will point us in a new direction, or the answer is simply NO.

Answer (score 0):

To store:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('example.html');
```

To output:

```
readfile('example.html');
```